# Convert '101.txt' Factor to Numeric in R

Tags: r

I have a column of a dataframe that consists of names of txt files. All these values are of type factor. For example:

[image]

How can I convert these values to numeric? For example, factor '1.txt' should be converted to 1, and '10.txt' should be converted to 10 etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Extract number from text : `as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(c('1.txt', '10.txt'), '\\d+'))`